# javascript hash values validation

Tags: javascript, duplicates

I'm trying to give the same behaviour to 4 values in my hash array.

For example:

```
var array = {};

  if (array[key].config.tmp == undefined) {
               array[key].config.tmp = {}
            }
            if(array[key].config.tmp.tp1){

            }
            if(array[key].config.tmp.tp2){

            }
            if(array[key].config.tmp.tp3){

            }
            if(array[key].config.tmp.tp4){

            }
```

Since tp1, tp2, tp3 and tp4 will have the same behaviour. I would like to simplify the validation.

Something like:

array[key].config.tmp.[tp1,tp2,tp3,tp4] is possible? Already tried. but it was

tp1,tp2,tp3 and tp4 may not exist(undefined). (tp1 and tp2 only sometimes).

Any advice so I won't duplicate code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use a filter on the array keys:

```
if ( ( array[key].config.tmp || {} ).keys().filter(
    function(k) { return /^tp[1234]/.test( k ) }
).length ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

use a short-circuit operator like `||`.  for instance, if you are checking for the existence of multiple properties, accessing a property which doesn't exist is falsy.

```
var c = a[key].config.tmp.a  || a[key].config.tmp.b || .... || //default
```

In this example, c will hold the value of the first of these to evaluate to true.  You could also include a "Default" value at the end if they all return false.  Keep in mind that accessing a property of a property that doesn't exist is a type error however, so you must be sure that at least config.tmp exists.  So you can replace your code with

```
if (a[key].config.tmp.a  || a[key].config.tmp.b || ....) {

}
```

Comment: That will work for the first step of my validation, but I will have a problem after.
Example:

If tp1 is undefined and should exist I need to attribute 9999 and with that validation I can't identify which tp is (if it's tp1 or tp2 or tp3 or tp4)